# Algorithm2e: Symbols look huge when written in \mathtt

Tags: algorithm2e

I have some algorithms and I want to set variables in typewriter mode.
Therefore I use \mathtt.
But then I have the impression that symbols like >>Greater or equal<< look to huge.
[image]

maybe my impression is wrong.
But I would have expected it to be a bit smaller.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german, linesnumbered, boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}


\newcommand{\pythonsyntax}{
    \SetStartEndCondition{ }{}{}%
    \SetKwProg{Fn}{Funktion}{:}{End}
    \SetKwFunction{Range}{range}%%
    \SetKw{KwTo}{in}\SetKwFor{For}{for}{\string:}{}%
    \SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{:}{elif}{else:}{endif}%
    \SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{endwhile}%
    \SetKwFor{For}{for}{:}{endfor}
    \SetKw{or}{or}
    \newcommand{\forcond}{$i$ \KwTo\Range{$n$}}
    \AlgoDontDisplayBlockMarkers
    \SetKw{in}{in}
}

\newcommand{\basic}{    
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetAlgoLined
    \SetKwInput{algoinput}{Eingabe}
    \SetKwInput{algooutput}{Ausgabe}
    \SetKw{return}{return}
    \SetKw{and}{and}
    \SetKw{continue}{continue}
    \SetKw{in}{in}
    \SetKw{to}{to}
    \newcommand{\algotrue}{\return\texttt{True}}
    \newcommand{\algofalse}{\return\texttt{False}}
}

\newcommand{\eingabe}[1]{\algoinput{#1}}
\newcommand{\ausgabe}[1]{\algooutput{#1}}
\newcommand{\funktion}[2]{\Fn{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{This is an MWE} \label{algo: findjacobikandidat}
        \basic
        \pythonsyntax
        \eingabe{Some variables \texttt{a} and \texttt{b}}
        \ausgabe{Some other variables}
        \funktion{$\mathtt{function(h, k, p)}$}{
            \If{$\mathtt{k  \geq 3}$}{\texttt{World ends}}
        }
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathtt` only changes the letters, not the symbols.